# Macro for defining kvc assessors in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macros, key-value-coding

Is there any macro to help simplify the creation of KVC macros in Objective C? As it stands in order to create a to-many mutable KVC compliant property is extremely tedious, to define a single property it takes the following

```
//Code.h
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *prevSearches;

//Code.m

@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSArray *prevSearches;

...

@synthesize prevSearches = _prevSearches;

- (void)prevSearches {
    return [_prevSearches copy];
}

- (void)setPrevSearches:(NSArray *)prevSearches {
    _prevSearches = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:prevSearches];
}

- (void)insertObject:(SavedSearch *)object inPrevSearchesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [_prevSearches insertObject:object atIndex:index];
}

- (void)removeObjectFromPrevSearchesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [_prevSearches removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

That's over 20 lines to define a single property, I often have several in a particular class...  Surely there's an easier way?

Comment: If all of these are really all the same except for the names, it would be trivial to write a macro to generate the code.

Comment: It actually seems like a tricky macro because the declaration spans 2 files and needs to handle different cases etc. Do you know of any similar macro that does this/

Answer (score 3):

have you tried a sofware like accessorizer?
http://itunes.apple.com/it/app/accessorizer/id402866670?mt=12
otherwise i think that a simple bash script can save your time ;)

Comment: accessorizer looks pretty awesome, i'm gonna give it a try now. Bash script as I understand is pretty good for generating new file but not generating code in place :)